# Writing an R loop to overcome API Limit

Tags: r

I am using the rcrossref library in R to try and call the Crossref API to pull article level data for a specific journal. However, I am running into issues because the CrossRef API has a limit of 1000 per request and for many journals there are more than 1000 articles. The problem is really two-fold. One is determining the number of articles and then creating a loop in order to overcome the 1000 request limit.

I have tried breaking up the data into smaller chunks, calling the api multiple times and then recombining later. While that does in fact work, the problem is that it immediately becomes very hard to scale up.

```r
# import needed libraries

library(rcrossref)

#Begin Harvesting DOIs from journals using Titles (will need to split up by dates in order to collect all articles from given year)
test_harvest1 <- cr_works(filter = c(container_title = 'The Gerontologist', from_pub_date = '2016-01-01', until_pub_date = '2016-02-29'), limit = 1000)
test_harvest2 <- cr_works(filter = c(container_title = 'The Gerontologist', from_pub_date = '2016-03-01', until_pub_date = '2016-04-30'), limit = 1000)
test_harvest3 <- cr_works(filter = c(container_title = 'The Gerontologist', from_pub_date = '2016-05-01', until_pub_date = '2016-06-30'), limit = 1000)
test_harvest4 <- cr_works(filter = c(container_title = 'The Gerontologist', from_pub_date = '2016-07-01', until_pub_date = '2016-08-31'), limit = 1000)
test_harvest5 <- cr_works(filter = c(container_title = 'The Gerontologist', from_pub_date = '2016-09-01', until_pub_date = '2016-10-31'), limit = 1000)
test_harvest6 <- cr_works(filter = c(container_title = 'The Gerontologist', from_pub_date = '2016-11-01', until_pub_date = '2016-12-31'), limit = 1000)
```

Comment: Is the API limit applied per request, per minute, per hour, per day,...?

Comment: The limit is applied per request.

Comment: Is each line or call to `cr_works` a request? Do you receive an error on limit?

Comment: Yes, each line calling '''r cr_works''' was my way to try and get around the limit. If you try to set the limit higher, you get an error saying that the limit parameter must be 1000 or less